# How to get the name of the shell running using a script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'd like to run a shell script that prints the name of the shell running it.

So far I've been using `echo $SHELL` but that variable may not be set and does not give the name of the current shell running the script.

I've tried with `ps -p $$` but this only works when using it directly in the terminal as in the script it gives me the name of the script file.

I have not found a good solution to this problem.

Current script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $SHELL
```

Thanks

EDIT: Just in case, I mean that I want to get the name of the command interpreter running the script by using a script.

Comment: Why do you need this? The name of the shell is in the `#!` line, why would it change from that?

Comment: dirty/ugly: `head -1 $0`? print out the shell's shebang. 'course, that won't want `. ./script`

Comment: On Linux `readlink -f /proc/$$/exe` gives you the path to the shell executable. If you want a reliable test, you would need to do some *feature fingerprinting* meaning checking for feature only a certain kind of shell supports.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Or `/proc/self/exe`  And `/proc/self/mapfiles` should have the actual binary, not just the scriptname

Comment: I'm sorry, I want the name of the command interpreter running the script.

Comment: FYI, `SHELL` should be set in anything POSIX-compliant, but it's value is the default shell, not necessarily the shell running the current script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something along these lines do what you want?

```
me@server2:~$ cat test
#!/bin/sh
X=$(ps h -p $$ -o args='' | cut -f1 -d' ')
echo "Running --> $X"    

me@server2:~$ ./test
Running --> /bin/sh
me@server2:~$ sh test
Running --> sh
me@server2:~$ bash test
Running --> bash
me@server2:~$
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I guess it has something to do with getting the process ID right?

Comment: Yes sorry, so I guess in words, here is what it does: report current processes with no header (the h option), applying no formatting (the -o args='' options), where process id is equal to reserved bash variable $$ (equal to process id of the running script) ... just in case you run into bugs, there are more [internal variables in bash](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
stat -tc '%N' /proc/$$/exe | cut -d' ' -f3
```

to get the name of the shell running the script

Answer (score 0):

After some tests, this seems to work on linux:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\0"}; NR==1{print; exit}' /proc/$$/cmdline
```

Requires a non-portable gawk feature.

Edit: An account of what happens here

The file /proc/PID/cmdline contains the complete command line from PID. `$$` expands to the current shell's PID. This file contains a NULL-byte seperated list of the complete command line. `gawk` is instructed to split the records ("lines") on the NULL-byte, and print the first one it encounters.

This would be a slightly shorter one:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{RS="\0"}; {print; exit}' /proc/$$/cmdline
```

Comment: This also works! Thank you! 
Although I don't understand how it works