# Identify the shell running in my system

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

Can anyone please tell me what shell has installed in my system?

Because when I am logging into my system using my username it is initially showing bash shell but later it is showing korn shell after doing sudo.

Please see below for details.

```
-bash-3.2$ pwd
/home/w4x2spxt
-bash-3.2$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
-bash-3.2$ su - XXXXXXX
Password:
You have new mail.
The Oracle base remains unchanged with value /apps/oracle
abc0300ab123:/a30/home/XXXXXXX >> echo $SHELL
/bin/ksh
```

Comment: "Running" and "installed" are two separate things.

Comment: check the shell mentioned against your username in `/etc/passwd` like this:  `grep ^XXXXXXX /etc/passwd`, to check all installed shells on your system use this:  `cat /etc/shells`

Comment: Thank you so much dear. It really makes sense.

Comment: Looks very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32191452/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-shell-running-using-a-script

Answer (score 1):

`SHELL` environment variable gives you your login shell.

check the shell path mentioned(last column) against your username or `XXXXXXX`(for `su`) in `/etc/passwd` like this: `grep ^XXXXXXX /etc/passwd`.

The shell mentioned in that file will be your default shell when you login or su to that user.

To check all installed shells on your system use this: `cat /etc/shells`

Comment: It is not mandatory for a shell to be in `/etc/shells`, see https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/unix/EtcShellsUsage

Answer (score 0):

- Your user is using `/bin/bash` as default shell.
- root is using `/bin/ksh` as its default shell.

The default shell is a user-specific setting, so there is nothing picky in having different ones among users. Just check the last column in `/etc/passwd` and surprise yourself with a variety of values.

Note by the way that when you do `su`, you log in as root. If you add the dash and say `su -` you are loading the root profile, so that you have its environment.

Comment: So a dash "-" makes a different during sud ?

Comment: @BikashKumarBehera yes. From `man su` --> _The optional argument `-` may be used to provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly_

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable `SHELL` always contains the login shell of the user logged in, defined in `/etc/passwd`.

If the user changes his/her shell after login by e.g. `exec bash` (`bash`), the `SHELL` will still expand to the login shell.

In your case, the user `XXXXXXX` has the login shell `/bin/ksh`, do:

```
grep '<user_name>' /etc/passwd
```

to match the results.

To find the current shell:

```
echo $0
```

Or

```
ps -p $$
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
-bash-3.2$ su - XXXXXXX
```

you are starting whatever shell is assigned to user `XXXXXXX`.  This is usually a good thing for `su -`, since that runs their shell as a login process so you get their normal shell startup initialization (profile, *shrc, etc). If you run a different shell from the one their account is set up for, you probably miss out on all their customization.

You can see what shell is associated with an account by looking them up in the password database.  This is pretty reliable across different types of systems and authentication schemes:

```
perl -MUser::pwent -le 'print( (getpwnam "XXXXXXX")->shell || "/bin/sh" )'
```

You can always run a shell explicitly as the other user if you have one in mind that you want:

```
su XXXXXXX -c "bash --login"
```

or

```
sudo -u XXXXXXX bash --login # if you have sudo privs
```

To see what shell you're currently running, look at `$0`:

```
echo $0
```

To see what shell you get by default as you, look at `$SHELL`.